# Using constants in gnome-shell theme css

Tags: gnome-shell

Is that possible to use kind of *constants* in `gnome-shell.css` theme file?

Something linke

```
@import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css");

@PANEL_ALPHA:0.5;

#panel {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,@PANEL_ALPHA);
}

.panel-corner {
    -panel-corner-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,@PANEL_ALPHA);
}
```

I also tried with `@const PANEL_ALPHA:0.5;` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) correctly (big if), no. The CSS version implemented by GTK3 only accepts a subset of the full CSS3 functionality. Specifically:

> GTK+ also supports an additional @define-color rule, in order to define a color name which may be used instead of color numeric representations. Also see the "gtk-color-scheme" setting for a way to override the values of these named colors.
>
> ```
> @define-color bg_color #f9a039;
>
> * {
>     background-color: @bg_color;
> }
> ```

So, you can define colors using the `@define-color` keyword but I don't think you can define arbitrary identifiers.

Comment: Have you tried that? I've tried in my theme but it doesn't work...

Comment: @lviggiani no I haven't, that was a direct quote from the official documentation (see the link in my answer). However, I checked in some of the themes I have installed and many do use it. For example: Adwaita, Menta, Albatross, Xfce-cadmium, Bluebird, Clearlooks-Phenix, GreenLaguna, you should be able to find all of these on http://gnome-look.org, download one and see how they do it.